# How to Publish Code Coverage results for Multiple Cobertura.xml file in TFS 2017 Build?

Tags: code-coverage, cobertura, azure-pipelines-build-task, istanbul

I am using **TFS 2017 Update3** and I have a Build definition which runs Grunt build task at two different HTML projects and generates two cobertura.xml files at their respective paths.

To display the code coverage result I have used **Publish Code Coverage Results task** in my build pipeline but it displays the Code coverage for only 1 project and doesn't display the code coverage result of other Html Project.

I tried using two **Publish Code Coverage Results task** each pointing to different cobertura.xml files but still it displays the code coverage result for only one project on TFS build summary.

Is there any other ways by which I can publish multiple code coverage result?

Comment: You could use the [ReportGenerator](https://github.com/danielpalme/ReportGenerator) cli tool to merge the files.